# sql server - checking existence for each row in insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

I need to do an insert and check for each row if the field "partita_iva" is already in this table, if yes the field "flag" must be 1, if not then must be 0. I did this, but it set 1 for all the rows, even if should be 1 just for one row

```
INSERT INTO tab2(id, flag)
select newid, 
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE partita_iva IN(SELECT partita_iva FROM tab2))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS flag
from tab1
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your code is quite unclear.

Comment: What are you trying to check, If column named partita_iva is existed or some value on partita_iva is existed ? Please ask question clearly.

Comment: @SagarTimalsina I want to check if values on partita_iva is existed, if there is already a value I have to set the flag to 1 for that value, with the code I provided I have 1 for all rows even if it should be 1 just for one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can probably be simplified.

```
INSERT INTO tab2 (id, flag)
SELECT t1.newid
, IIF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tab2 t2 WHERE t2.partita_iva = t1.partita_iva), 1, 0) AS flag
FROM tab1 t1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current query logic seems correct to me, but you can correlate your sub-query :

```
INSERT INTO tab2(id, flag)
      SELECT NEWID(), CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                                       FROM tab2 t2 
                                       WHERE t2.partita_iva = t1.partita_iva 
                                      )
                           THEN 1 ELSE 0
                      END AS flag
      FROM tab1 t1;
```

[`NEWID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a function that will creates a unique value of type uniqueidentifier.

Answer (score 0):

As a total stab in the dark:

```
INSERT INTO tab2(Id,Flag)
SELECT newid, --Do you mean NEWID()?
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tab2 T2 WHERE T2.partita_iva = T1.partita_iva) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM tab1 T1;
```